# Trying to send data with serial port communication

Tags: serial-port

I am trying to use serial port communication to send data via xBee, but it is not working and I don't know why. It is not running, it is saying that is unable to start the program and "The System cannot find the file specified". I would appreciate it if someone could help me.

Here is the code that I am using to test it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <commdlg.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    DCB dcb;
    HANDLE hCom;
    BOOL fSuccess;
    COMMTIMEOUTS timeouts;
    char *buffWrite;
    DWORD dwBytesWritten = 0;

    hCom = CreateFile( L"COM9",
                    GENERIC_WRITE,
                    0,    // must be opened with exclusive-access
                    NULL, // no security attributes
                    OPEN_EXISTING, // must use OPEN_EXISTING
                    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,    // not overlapped I/O
                    NULL  // hTemplate must be NULL for comm devices
                    );

    if (hCom == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
    {
        // Handle the error.
        printf ("CreateFile failed with error %d.\n", GetLastError());
        return (1);
    }

    // Build on the current configuration, and skip setting the size
    // of the input and output buffers with SetupComm.

    fSuccess = GetCommState(hCom, &dcb);

    if (!fSuccess) 
    {
        // Handle the error.
        printf ("GetCommState failed with error %d.\n", GetLastError());
        return (2);
    }

    // Fill in DCB: 9,600 bps, 8 data bits, no parity, and 1 stop bit.

    dcb.BaudRate = CBR_9600;     // set the baud rate
    dcb.ByteSize = 8;             // data size, xmit, and rcv
    dcb.Parity = NOPARITY;        // no parity bit
    dcb.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;    // one stop bit

    fSuccess = SetCommState(hCom, &dcb);

    if (!fSuccess) 
    {
        // Handle the error.
        printf ("SetCommState failed with error %d.\n", GetLastError());
        return (3);
    }

    GetCommTimeouts(hCom,&timeouts);
    //COMMTIMEOUTS timeouts = {0};

    timeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout = MAXDWORD;
    timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 0;
    timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 0;
    timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 1000;
    timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier= 10;

    if(!SetCommTimeouts(hCom, &timeouts)) 
    {
        printf("error setting port state \n");
    }

    buffWrite = "Testing Serial Port!";

    if (WriteFile(hCom,   // handle to file to write to
                buffWrite,              // pointer to data to write to file
                sizeof(buffWrite),              // number of bytes to write
                &dwBytesWritten,NULL) == 0)      // pointer to number of bytes written
            {
                printf("Reading of serial communication has problem.");
                return FALSE;
            }

    CloseHandle(hCom);
}
```

Thank You.
Jack.

Comment: None of your code is relevant until you can convince the operating system to find the executable you need.  It is completely unclear how you start it and what kind of DLL dependencies you might have.  Use SysInternals' ProcMon utility for diagnostics.

Comment: Does it fail with the message `CreateFile failed with error...` ?

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume for a moment that the question posted by @rm5248 is on the mark and that you are talking about the program compiled from the code you posted is failing with `CreateFile failed with error The system cannot find file specified`.

The most likely cause is therefore that the COM Port you are opening does not exist.  If you are using Windows then use a command prompt and the `MODE | MORE` which will list for you available Com Ports on your system. Note that com ports are not shown in this list if being used.

Once you know of what ports you have available change the line in you code `hCom = CreateFile( L"COM1",`